# I need to alter lines of a unix file that contain a certain string

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, ksh

I have a file with lines of a set format, using delimiters. I want to identify all the lines with the string "password"  in the 3rd field and edit them out. As in, put a "# " at the beginning of them.
I would also like to remove the existing value for the 4th field.
I can't quite work out how to do this. It looks like it should be able to be done in two steps but I cannot work them out. I am using unix shell, so SED, AWK etc.
Sample lines of the file are:

```
database2|~|t1||~|${topuser.username}|~|topuser
database2|~|t1||~|${topuser.password}|~|H4rdt0Gu3ss
database2|~|t1||~|${loguser.username}|~|LOG
database2|~|t1||~|${loguser.password}|~|Ih4v3n01d34y0utry
# database2|~|t1||~|${open.var1}|~|connect
database2|~|t1||~|${tablespace}|~|gis_tbs1
```

Some may be edited out already and the delimeter is "|~|".
Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Perl script to achieve your goal:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /\|~\|/;
    if ($fields[2] =~ /password/) {
        $fields[0] = "# $fields[0]";
        $fields[3] = '';
    }
    print join("|~|", @fields), "\n";
}

__DATA__
database2|~|t1||~|${topuser.username}|~|topuser
database2|~|t1||~|${topuser.password}|~|H4rdt0Gu3ss
database2|~|t1||~|${loguser.username}|~|LOG
database2|~|t1||~|${loguser.password}|~|Ih4v3n01d34y0utry
# database2|~|t1||~|${open.var1}|~|connect
# database2|~|t1||~|${tablespace}|~|gis_tbs1
```

Here is the one-liner version:

```
perl -F'/\|~\|/' -ane '$"="|~|"; if ($F[2] =~ /password/) { $F[0]="# $F[0]"; $F[3] = "\n"; } print "@F";' datafile
```

Comment: In one-liner: `perl -lpe '@F=split /\|~\|/; $F[0]="# $F[0]" and $F[3]="" if $F[2]=~/password/; $_=join "|~|", @F' file` `:)`

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If I understood your question correctly, then the following should work:</strike>

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\|"}$6~/password/{$6="# "$6;$NF=""}1' file
database2|~|t1||~|${topuser.username}|~|topuser
database2|~|t1||~|# ${topuser.password}|~|
database2|~|t1||~|${loguser.username}|~|LOG
database2|~|t1||~|# ${loguser.password}|~|
# database2|~|t1||~|${open.var1}|~|connect
database2|~|t1||~|${tablespace}|~|gis_tbs1
```

If you mean **edit them out** by putting **`#`** at the **start of the line**, then you can do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\|"}$6~/password/{$NF="";$0="# "$0}1' file
database2|~|t1||~|${topuser.username}|~|topuser
# database2|~|t1||~|${topuser.password}|~|
database2|~|t1||~|${loguser.username}|~|LOG
# database2|~|t1||~|${loguser.password}|~|
# database2|~|t1||~|${open.var1}|~|connect
database2|~|t1||~|${tablespace}|~|gis_tbs1
```

Comment: So I screwed up my sample data. Added an extra |. Should have looked like this.

    database2|~|t1|~|${topuser.username}|~|topuser
    database2|~|t1|~|${topuser.password}|~|

Used this, thanks.

    cat t | awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} $5 ~ /password/ { $7=""; printf("#%s\n", $0) }; $5 !~ /password/ {print $0}'

Comment: @Sparkle You can do `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\|"}$5~/password/{$NF="";$0="# "$0}1' file` this instead. Short and simple.

Comment: OP: If you want equality, not containment, change `~` to `==`. Your question is unclear on whether you want to look for "password" exactly, or as a substring anywhere within the field's value.